# Xcode9 Display range drift

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, layout

I use Xcode9 and MacOS Mojave ,I don't know why , the storyboard layout looks like alway Drift upward . but It is correct to run.but only looks drift in storyboard:

[image]

can any one tell me why?and how to fix it?

Comment: That might be the bug in storyboard in Xcode 9, try to refresh it by zoom in & out to update the UI rendering correctly.

Comment: I tried , but not work for me